# Div showing like a Modal

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, lightbox

Is there a way to show a div at the same shadow like a modal?

I have a Modal. When the modal appears I also want to show a `DIV` containing a message in the left corner.
This `DIV` should appear in front of the modal, but it doesn't.

I have tried the following without success.

```
.div{
  z-index:9999;
  position:absolute;
}
```

**NOTE** im using [lightbox](http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/) to render the modal containing an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Z-index and position should work, try with this.

```
.div{
  z-index: 9999;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white; /* just to see if the div is there */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```